# Why does .NET string.Equals check 5 characters per loop? (6 on AMD)

Tags: c#, .net, string, optimization, micro-optimization

Found an odd thing in the .Net source when looking at `String`. In the `Equals` helper:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,11648d2d83718c5e,references for checking string equality, it checks four bytes at a time (I think), but each iteration of the loop does five checks, each progressing two positions. (and does six for AMD, which is also odd)

I'm assuming this is some specific micro-optimization they've done, but why is it faster to check five times in a loop rather than looping 5 times?

I feel I haven't explained it well, but the source is in the link, which will explain it better.

```
    private unsafe static bool EqualsHelper(String strA, String strB)
    {
        Contract.Requires(strA != null);
        Contract.Requires(strB != null);
        Contract.Requires(strA.Length == strB.Length);

        int length = strA.Length;

        fixed (char* ap = &strA.m_firstChar) fixed (char* bp = &strB.m_firstChar)
        {
            char* a = ap;
            char* b = bp;

            // unroll the loop
#if AMD64
            // for AMD64 bit platform we unroll by 12 and
            // check 3 qword at a time. This is less code
            // than the 32 bit case and is shorter
            // pathlength

            while (length >= 12)
            {
                if (*(long*)a     != *(long*)b) return false;
                if (*(long*)(a+4) != *(long*)(b+4)) return false;
                if (*(long*)(a+8) != *(long*)(b+8)) return false;
                a += 12; b += 12; length -= 12;
            }
#else
            while (length >= 10)
            {
                if (*(int*)a != *(int*)b) return false;
                if (*(int*)(a+2) != *(int*)(b+2)) return false;
                if (*(int*)(a+4) != *(int*)(b+4)) return false;
                if (*(int*)(a+6) != *(int*)(b+6)) return false;
                if (*(int*)(a+8) != *(int*)(b+8)) return false;
                a += 10; b += 10; length -= 10;
            }
#endif

            // This depends on the fact that the String objects are
            // always zero terminated and that the terminating zero is not included
            // in the length. For odd string sizes, the last compare will include
            // the zero terminator.
            while (length > 0) 
            {
                if (*(int*)a != *(int*)b) break;
                a += 2; b += 2; length -= 2;
            }

            return (length <= 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mean performing a single comparison per loop body? You'd then be performing one length comparison per character comparison, instead of only performing 1/5 as many length comparisons as character comparisons.

Comment: "What is [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling)?"

Comment: AMD64 just means x86 for 64 bit.

Comment: @JonSkeet so it's to reduce the number of times the loop condition is checked, rather than the comparisons within the loop body itself? That makes sense. Thanks :)

Comment: @demo, please don't edit just to change from British spelling to American spelling. "optimisation" is perfectly correct English.

Comment: @elgonzo: The variables `a` and `b` are `char *`, so `a += 2;` moves it along 4 bytes.

Comment: @JonSkeet, lol, you are right. My mind subconsciously switched to C when seeing `char*`. Oh dear... ;-)